# Create a Google spreadsheet using Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-data-api

i want to create a New Spreadsheet using Java(Google App Engine)

I am passing a json string to my servlet.What i want this servlet to do is:
1.authorize/authenticate using oauth2
2. create a spreadsheet of this data on google drive

All the library combinations are so confusing,which library should i uae for which purpose.
Gdata.., drive-api jar, oauth jar,sheets api.
I read the sheets APi,which clearly mentions that to creata a New Spreadaheet i should use Drive API

Please point me in right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You need to authorize your requests to Google APIs using OAuth2: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

You need the Drive API to create sheets and save them to Drive: https://developers.google.com/drive/

You need the Sheets API to work with the actual spreadsheets (editing the file): https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/?hl=en

Comment: 1. how do i authorize my Google API calls using oauth2. i want to use my gmail credentials,or wat else should i use for server to server communication 2. Can you show me some sample code on how to use the oauth to hit the Drive APi to create spreadsheet

Comment: If you read the Drive API link, there is a step by step tutorial there on how to set up OAuth2. Any Google account credential will work (so gmail is fine). There are also tutorials for using spreadsheets after you setup OAuth in the sheets link I posted. The last two links both have good tutorials on how to set up OAuth2, access Drive, and create a spreadsheet. You need to read through those websites.

Comment: Thanks for the help.I have one more query, looking through the docs ,i checked i have to use OFFLINE mode to authenticate my application to access Google API.Its mentioned i have to exchange the "authorization code" for the "access token". How will i get this authorization code? i am not sure about this

Comment: its all in those drive auth section in the official docs. also google more to understand what is oauth.

Comment: @zee I haven't used that so I'm not sure, but we can refer to Zigs comment (thanks Zig)

Comment: @ZigMandel  i have succesfully connected using oauth in appengine(AppIdentityCredential) and sent an authorised request to Drive to retrieve file list. What i would want is AppIdentityCredential to use my Google Account Credentials (instead of App Engine Application Service Account). What modfications should i do

Comment: @zee integrating Google is not a "quick" addition to your application. You need to spend time and research, search for examples/tutorials, browse stack overflow, and *then* if you get stuck on a specific problem come here for help. We can't walk you through the entire process. I think this question has been answered.

Comment: too broad. see official docs about how a 3legged oauth2 flow works. play here so you see the practical steps involved: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ which can also be used as a way to get the refresh token and hardcode in your app. saves your some code but will later be harder to reconfigure.